# Should a user be able to see deleted questions in another user's favorites?

Tags: discussion, bug, bookmarks

Whether or not being able to see deleted questions which I once favorited in my profile is useful or not, I'm not sure of the benefit of being able to see deleted questions in ***another*** users' favorites list.

What makes this even more questionable is that I can do this on non-10k users, who can't even see *their own* deleted-favorites.

Is this behavior desired? *I don't think that other users should be able to see actions by me that I can't see myself (in the case where 10k users can see non-10k deleted favorites that they can't see).*

Comment: "Favourites" is just a mechanism to keep track of a question, almost every time I favourite a question it's _not_ because I like it, quite the opposite really. Just saying...

Comment: @Yannis I know a lot of people favorite a question just to keep track of it, but I think the name favorite suggests that it's a question that you like and thus want to be able to find later easily; that's how I use it, and I think that's how it's intended to be used.

Comment: @PeterOlson Ah, the ages old divide between theory and practice ;)

Comment: @Yannis In theory, there is no divide between theory and practice :)